# laravel ajax get doesn't return anything dropdown json

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, get, return

i'm a newbie study laravel
now i want to make a dropdown which is filled by books title, and if i choose title, other information will come up
i made this dropdown on sales.create view

this is my sales create blade

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::select('books[]',$books,null,['class' => 'form-control input-sm','name' => 'book_title', 'id' => 'book_title'])}}
</div>

<script>
    $('#book_title').on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var book_id = e.target.value;
        //ajax
        $.get('ajax-book_data?book_id=' + book_id, function(data){
            //success data
            console.log(data);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

and this is my route

```
Route::resource('books','BooksController');
Route::resource('sales','SalesController');

Route::get('/sales/create',function(){
    $books = [];
    foreach (Book::all() as $book):
        $books[$book->id] = $book->title;
    endforeach;
    return View::make('sales.create')->with('books',$books);
});

Route::get('/ajax-book_data', function(){
    $book_id = Input::get('book_id');
    $book_data = Book::where('id', '=', $book_id)->get();
    var_dump($book_id);
    var_dump($book_data);
    return Respone::json($book_data);
});
```

on table 'book'
i have id, title, author_id, publisher_id field.

is anyone can help?
thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?  HttpNotFound exception?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (If I get your question right):

I assume with this line of your code:

```
return View::make('sales.create')->with('books',$books);
```

You can do something like this in your view:

```
<ul>
@foreach($books as $listBook)
<li class="ajaxUse">
<a book-id="{{ $listBook->id }}">{{ $listBook->title }}</a>
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Note that I added an attribute to "`<a>`" tag "`book-id`" which holds the current book's id with a class in "`<li>`". We use both to retrieve the value after user click.
Here is ajax:
Jquery.js needed.

```
$('ajaxUse a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var bookId = $(this).attr("book-id");
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:  "{{ URL::route('getPostBookDetail') }}",
         data:  {currentBookId : bookId},
         cache: false,
         dataType: "json", 
         success : function(data){
         if(data){
         alert("It's working");
}

}

       })
});
```

Then in your routes.php you can have something like this:

```
Route::post('/book-detail', array( 'as' => 'getPostBookDetail','uses' => 'UserController@getPostBook'));
```

Then finally in your controller (i.e: UserController.php) you will have this:

```
public function getPostBook(){
  $bookId = Input::get('currentBookId'); //From ajax post
  $getDetails = Book::where('id', $bookId)->first();

//Json data to return to ajax call
$response = array('status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'You got book details successfully');
  if(count($getDetails)){
   return Response::json($response);
}
}
```

I hope this help.

Good luck.